# How many graphs have $n$ vertices and $m$ edges?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

I tried many ways to solve this but failed.

Any tips **or** way to solve?

Comment: We need to know more about the graph. Is it connected? Are edges allowed to connect a vertex to itself?

Comment: Do you consider two graphs the same if they are isomorphic? If not (that is, we count "labeled graphs"), the answer is $${{n \choose 2} \choose m}.$$

Comment: Think about it as if each edge represent picking $2$ vertices (like 2 balls from an urn of $n$ balls) and with replacement ofcourse because anothe edge maybe connected to the same vertex